# How to make wordpress cookie authentication?

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

I am using json auth api to authenticate the user.

i am using my wordpress site hosted on 000webhost with https protocol.

When i am logging in i am getting this error message :

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized
```

What I have tried:

```
var webRequest =(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://mahdii.000webhostapp.com/users/auth/generate_auth_cookie/?nonce=my_nonce&username=my_username&password=my_password");
webRequest.Method = "GET";
webRequest.ContentLength = 0; // added per comment
string autorization = "username" + ":" + "Password";
byte[] binaryAuthorization =System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(autorization);
autorization = Convert.ToBase64String(binaryAuthorization);
autorization = "Basic " + autorization;
webRequest.Headers.Add("AUTHORIZATION", autorization);
var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
if (webResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK) Console.WriteLine("{0}", webResponse.Headers);
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(s);
reader.Close();
}
```

Please i need help,suggestions would be appreciated.

I am pretty sure all the url parameters are correct !

Comment: Your endpoint for creating the authentication token should not require authentication as this is the one in charge of authenticating the user, this means it should allow non-authenticated users.

One suggestion: Try to change your code to use HttpClient instead of WebRequest.

Comment: Sorry i don t know how to write the code for it correctly.